# How to force WebBrowser Control to repaint and redraw the webpage elements

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, webbrowser-control

I use a webbrowser control in a form. To allow the user to manipulate the webpage, I add the control to a new form in which the user can hide some HTML elements.  It is how I hide an element:

```
  IHTMLElement2 dom = item.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
  dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "hidden";
```

When the user close this second form, I switch the hidden and visible elements and add the WebBrowser again to my main form. This is the code to switch the visibility of elements, to do this I make the `body` hidden and the hidden elements visible :

```
void SwitchVisibility()
{
    IHTMLElement bodyDom = wb.Document.Body.DomElement as IHTMLElement;
    bodyDom.style.visibility = "hidden";

    foreach (var item in addedElements)
    {
        IHTMLElement2 dom = item.DomElement as IHTMLElement2;
        dom.runtimeStyle.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

I called the procedure above in `form2_closing` even and once after `form2.ShowDialog()` in the main form, but these changes are not reflected on the control unless I minimize and maximize the main form. I should add if I don't switch the visibility of elements, the changes are reflected! Also, if I put the code above in the `click` event of a button, the desired changes are shown.

I used `Refresh` method of the **webbrowser** but it actually reloads the document, then I used `Refresh` method of the main form but it also doesn't work. I wonder how the document and its elements' visibility are refreshed.

Comment: If you are sure you need to repaint the control, you can try `webBrowser1.Invalidate();`

Comment: @RezaAghaei As I minimize and maximize the main form, I see the desired content. However, using `invalidate()`, after `form2.ShowDialog()` also doesn't work.

Comment: So maybe its better to share a simple code to reproduce the problem. Because now we only can guess somethings.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I try, but I just wonder what happens to WebBrowser Document when I minimize and maximize the form except repainting and invalidating.

Comment: I tested such scenario and it works properly. Without seeing the whole reproduction code I have no idea about what may cause the problem.

Comment: @RezaAghaei yeah, describing the real problem is a bit hard, actually I switch the visibile and hidden contents, to do this I make the `body` hidden and the `hidden` elements visible

Comment: Add [this class](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CbyuW5) to your project and run it as your startup form. This is what I tested and works properly. And let me know the result.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thank you very much for you help, however, meanwhile I posted my solution! please check it, it seems my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tested, I must call the `SwitchVisibility` in the main form after the form2 was closed and the `webbrowser` was added to the main form as follows:

```
        FormBrowser browser = new FormBrowser();
        browser.Browser = webBrowser1;

        browser.ShowDialog();


        // Readd the webbrowser1
        panel1.Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
        webBrowser1.Location = loc;
        webBrowser1.Size = size;
        webBrowser1.BringToFront();

        // if this function is called in `Closing` 
        // event of form2, the chanes are not reflected.

        SwitchVisibility(addedElements);
        /// To reassure repainting (however it works without it too)
        webBrowser1.Invalidate();
```